# Multilanguage + Astro & LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, astrojs

I want to create an astro component taking into account a variable in localstorage to get each component text, but Astro shows null.

```
let locale = "en"; //default
const userLanguage = localStorage.getItem("language");
if (userLanguage ) {
locale = userLanguage;
} let menu;
import(`../locale/${locale}/menu.json`).then((lang) =\> {
menu  = lang.default;
});
```

I need to find the way to have language based json or markup files and load each user's language. I was thinking about using svelte/react but I will have to create a lot of calls or maybe is there another way to make it?

Answer (score 6):

### Why it happens

As I understood you want to create `*.astro` component and use `localStorage` API within it. However, browser related API (such as `document` and `window`) **is not accessible on the server i.e. in Astro** and from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) you can see that `localStorage` is part of `window` object.

> The **`localStorage`** read-only property of the `window` interface allows you to access a `Storage` object for the `Document`'s origin; the stored data is saved across browser sessions.

With that in mind the right usage of `localStorage` will be `window.localStorage` which will cause the [following Astro error](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/troubleshooting/#document-or-window-is-not-defined):

> `document` (or `window`) is not defined

From Astro docs you can see what this actually means:

> Astro components run on the server, so you can’t access these browser-specific objects within the frontmatter.

### Potential solutions

So the **potential solution** will be to use Framework components with lifecycle hooks (e.g React's `useEffect`, Vue's `onMounted` and so on)  or `<script>` as mentioned in [Astro docs](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/troubleshooting/#document-or-window-is-not-defined) as well:

> If the code is in an Astro component, move it to a `<script>` tag outside of the frontmatter. This tells Astro to run this code on the client, where `document` and `window` are available.

> If the code is in a framework component, try to access these objects after rendering using lifecycle methods ... Tell the framework component to hydrate client-side by using a `client:` directive, like `client:load`, to run these lifecycle methods.

### How would I solve it

Hovewer, from my experience I would move the async loading of `json` translation from the client to the server by just loading all the translations, i.e for each language.

Let's say you have the following folder structure for translations:

```
- locales
--- menu
----- en.json
----- ru.json
----- es.json
--- other_feature
----- en.json
----- ru.json
----- es.json
```

Then we can use glob import to import everything at once:

```js
const translations = import.meta.glob('./locales/menu/*.json', { eager: true, import: 'default' })
```

Then you just pass this translations object (which is object with keys representing path to file and values representing the `json` string) to your Framework component. You can learn more about glob import [here](https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#glob-import).

Framework component itself should use lifecycle method to access the `localStorage` to read user locale and conditionally take the correct translation from the input props. Below the Vue example:

```js
<script setup>
import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue'

const props = defineProps(['translations'])
const translation = ref({})

onMounted(() => {
  const userLocale = window.localeStorage.getItem("language")
  // take the correct translation from all translations
  translation.value = JSON.parse(
    translations[Object.keys(translations).find(key => key.includes(userLocale))]
  )
})
</script>

<template>
  <p>This message displayed in your mother tongue: {{ translation.message }}</p>
</template>
```

So the final Astro file can look like this:

```
---
const translations = import.meta.glob('./locales/menu/*.json', { eager: true, import: 'default' })
---

<div>
  <!-- Keep in mind that using `client:load` you might face hydration issues. They can be resolved by explicitly rendering the component on the client using `client:only` -->
  <VueMessageComponent translations={ translations } client:load />
</div>
```

I hope it helps but keep in mind that I wrote that in JavaScript (not in TypeScript) which can cause some issues with `null`/`undefined` values. Also, I did not test this code so it might not work just out of the box :)